# switch between forms from main program

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

what i have to do is  kiosk app that read informations from a serial port and switch between three different forms depending on data received. forms can also switch between each other by button.

simplyfing:

1 Form1 active until data received

2 main program read data

3 form1 closed

4 form2 opend and elaborate recived data

5 form2 button clicked

6 form3 opened

7 form 2 closed

8 loop restart

my approach
is to use this example 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7536/How-To-Swap-Top-Level-Forms?msg=969882 and i make this modify to ApplicationContext but if i use originale example it work but i don't know how to pass method with delegate, if i use modified  code a can pass delegate bu form freeze and some time form not open. i.m not sure that tis is the bast way, i cannot move readin serial data to form1

any suggestion or example to follow?

```
public class MainFormManager : ApplicationContext
    {
        protected bool exitAppOnClose;

        // original 

        //Declare delagete callback function, the owner of communication
        public SetOrderDelegate ProcessOrder;

        public Form CurrentForm {
            get { return MainForm; }
            set {
                if (MainForm != null) {
                    // close the current form, but don't exit the application
                    exitAppOnClose = false;
                    MainForm.Close();
                    exitAppOnClose = true;
                }
                // switch to the new form
                MainForm = value;
                MainForm.Show();


            }
        }
        // modified 
        private Frm1 frm1;
        private Frm2 frm2;
        private Frm3 frm3;

        public void ShowFrm1()
        {
            if (frm1 == null) {
                frm1 = new Frm1();
                frm1.Closed += mainFormClosed; // avoid reshowing a disposed form
                this.ProcessOrder += new SetOrderDelegate(frm1.ProcessOrder);
                MainForm = frminizio;
                MainForm.Show();
            } else {
                frm1.Activate();
            }
        }


        private void mainFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frminizio = null;
        }

        public void ShowFrm2()
        {
            if (frm2 == null) {
                frm2 = new Frm2();
                frm1.Closed += frm2Closed; // avoid reshowing a disposed form
                //this.ProcessOrder += new SetOrderDelegate(frm3.ProcessOrder);
                MainForm.Close();
                MainForm = frm2;
                MainForm.Show();
            } else {
                frm2.Activate();
            }
        }


        private void frm2Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm2 = null;
        }

        public void ShowFrm3()
        {
            if (frm3 == null) {
                frm3 = new Frm3();
                frm3.Closed += frm3Closed; // avoid reshowing a disposed form
                //this.ProcessOrder += new SetOrderDelegate(frm3.ProcessOrder);
                MainForm.Close();
                MainForm = frm3;
                MainForm.Show();
            } else {
                frmPaga.Activate();
            }
        }


    internal sealed class Program
        {

    public Program()
            {
                //all other stuff
                Application.Run(mainFormManager);
            }


    static void SerialReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);

                //SetTextDeleg BcRun = BarCodeRun;
                string data = serial.ReadLine();
                if (data == true) {
// this is only a semplyfied example     //
                 frm1.setdata(data);
                 task.loop (2000);
                 frm2.setdata(data);
                 frm1.close();
                 frm2.open();

                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It freezes because you have `Thread.Sleep(500)` in your SerialReceived method.  So if you get a bunch of data, you'll be frozen pretty much at all times.

You shouldn't have thread pauses in your serial IO events because it backs up the data and depending on the baud speed you are going at, you'll likely lose data (the underlying chip, called UART doesn't carry a lot of onboard memory to store all the buffered data).

Comment: sleep is only to for this example here to sempify how is everithing work, is not included in my project, serial work perfect @angryHacker

Comment: Ok, so can you pinpoint the line of code where the program hangs?

Comment: when i call for example ShowFrm2() for example, my problem is handlig form and send data to it @angryHacker

Comment: @andymo Which specific line in ShowFrm2 causes the hang?

Comment: @andymo I think the pattern is just wrong.  You are using MainForm as a variable, even though you have CurrentForm that wraps it.  As far as MainForm.show, you have `MainForm = frm2;` then `MainForm.Show();`.  So we are really talking about frm2.show().   You might want to look at what's in the constructor for frm2 or in the Load event of frm2.  It's possible something there is blocking it.

Comment: In general, you should .Close & .Dispose the forms.  And you need to be consistent, for instance in ShowFrm2 you are using MainForm to abstract the forms, while in SerialReceived you are opening and closing forms directly.  There is probably a memory leak somewhere where the references get out of control.

Comment: i have tried even with frm.show but no lucky, frm2 has no control in this moment, do you think that is the right approach to manage forms anyway?

Comment: i modified to form2 as u suggested but now it tell me that is a cross tread operation closing frm1

Comment: @andymo It's an all right way, but you have to be disciplined about it.  You have to have a single way to close and open forms (e.g. openForm(frm), closeForm(frm) etc....  When you close it, you should dispose it.  Right now, it's all over the place, which is what is causing your hang probably.  If all your form have a setData method, you should probably create a base form that has that method and let frm1, frm2, etc... inherit from it, so that you can just reference a generic form.

Comment: @andymo Regarding cross-thread, yeah - you have to handle that - you would have gotten that sooner or later.  `SerialReceived` is firing on a separate thread, you have to marshal it to your UI thread.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917810/cross-thread-invalidoperationexception-while-trying-to-access-serialport-dynamic) for doing that.